# Using only CSS, can I use only the alpha channel of a PNG?

Tags: css, webkit, png, transparency, alpha

I have this red PNG image that has variable transparency, but I need to display it on the web page as white with variable transparency. I'm thinking there's only two ways this might work:

- Set the background-color to white, but somehow use the alpha channel of the PNG to set its transparency.
- Somehow de-saturate the PNG or change its color palette to only white.

I'm only allowed to use CSS to achieve this goal; otherwise, I'd look into other options.

**Edit**: I only need this to work in Safari (webkit). Sorry I didn't mention this before.

Comment: What browsers do you need this to work in? It might be possible with IE`s `filter`s

Comment: ...or webkit image mask.

Comment: @Litek, it worked! Now create a solution so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Requested answer:

[`-webkit-mask`](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/) can take an image and use it's alpha channel as mask (pretty much like photoshop mask)

```
div {
  background:white;
  -webkit-mask:url(url/to/image.png);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vB5pQ/10/#edit)

But I agree with all of the answers suggesting canvas - I know you're limited to pure css, but canvas is a way to go here.

Comment: Yep. I love canvas, but this is a CSS challenge. Thanks for a great answer :)

Comment: It looks like the original uploader of the image you used doesn't like that you hotlinked it. Maybe change it to something from Wikimedia Commons.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot do this in a cross-browser manner using only CSS.

*(It would be rather easy to do this using an HTML5 Canvas along with your image, however.)*

**Canvas Solution**:

You can view this example live here: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_png_alpha.html

```js
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function(){
  // Make the canvas the same size as the image
  var w = ctx.canvas.width  = img.width;
  var h = ctx.canvas.height = img.height;

  // Fill it with (fully-opaque) white
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff'; ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

  // Draw the image in a special blend mode that forces its opacity on the result
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  // Set an image on the page to use this canvas data
  // The data URI can also be copy/pasted and used inline in HTML or CSS
  document.getElementById('result').src=ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
}

// Load the image to use _after_ setting the onload handler
img.src = 'alphaball.png';
```

The [source image](http://phrogz.net/tmp/alphaball.png) whose alpha is being used:
[image: A round ball with a couple holes and transparent shadow]
The [result](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_png_alpha.html) (shown on a black page):
[image: white silhouette on black background]

The key here is using the [`destination-in`](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/) compositing mode to use the opacity of the source image as the result, while leaving the original colors (in this case white) intact.

Comment: Very cool and I'll most likely use this for other things in the future, but this simply doesn't answer the question, based on the limitations that are set. Sorry.

Comment: @sfjedi No problem; I'm glad you asked the CSS-only version and edited to note Webkit-only. I didn't know about `webkit-mask` and am pleased to have found out about it.

Answer (score 3):

In IE versions less than 9 there is the [chroma filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which does this. In other browsers, you are out of luck.

You could use the canvas tag with some javascript to get the same effect, but that isn't CSS.